# nodes labels after deleting in R

Tags: r, rstudio, igraph

I'm working with random graphs where the label of nodes are numbers from 1 to N. In my work, I'm deleting some nodes from the graph. My problem is that in R, after deleting is just renaming the nodes again from 1 to remaining N, how I can preserve the label of nodes after deleting ??
thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO! It might be helpful to add some extra content, including some code you've tried and providing specific examples. Check out [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no name for a node, the node ID (number) is used to label the graph. To preserve the label, set the *name* of the nodes to their IDs before removing nodes. Here is a small example.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.35)
plot(g)

for(i in 1:vcount(g)) { 
    V(g)[i]$name = i }

g2 = delete_vertices(g, c(3,8))
plot(g2)
```

[image: Graph with deleted nodes]

Note that the old labels are preserved.